# jQuery to change image src with modification on click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have one larger image with two smaller thumbnails beneath it - Marked up as follows:

```
<img src="../images/image.jpg" class="left" alt="main image" />
<img src="../images/image2-thumb.jpg" class="left" alt="image two" />
<img src="../images/image3-thumb.jpg" class="left thumb" alt="image three" />
```

I would like when image2-thumb or image3-thumb is clicked for it to change image.jpg to the clicked images src BUT without the -thumb.

so if i click image2-thumb.jpg then image.jpg becomes image2.jpg and so on.

Can anyone point me in the right direction to get this to work?

Comment: Can we see your unsuccessful attempts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how you can do: http://jsfiddle.net/aamir/8AeHv/

HTML:

```
<img src="../images/image.jpg" class="left main" alt="main image" />
<img src="../images/image2-thumb.jpg" class="left thumb" alt="image two" />
<img src="../images/image3-thumb.jpg" class="left thumb" alt="image three" />
```

JS:

```
$(function () {
    $('.thumb').click(function () {
        $('.main').attr('src', this.src.replace('-thumb', ''))
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

use:

```
<img src="../images/image.jpg" class="left" alt="main image" />
<img src="../images/image2-thumb.jpg" class="right" alt="image two" />
<img src="../images/image3-thumb.jpg" class="right thumb" alt="image three" />

$('.right').click(function(){
    $('.left').attr('src',$(this).attr('src').replace('-thumb',''));
    alert($('.left').attr('src'));
});
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Pn7n3/1/)**